# Load non-standard lua library in sandbox (Lua 5.1/Luajit)

Tags: lua, sandbox, luajit, lua-5.1

I'm trying to familiarize myself with lua and I'm playing around with the coding game berrybots (http://berrybots.com/) for that end. It uses a C++ engine and the users/players can provide lua scripts to program their own "bot AI" to battle against other bots.

I'm programming my own bot, but I want to use some more numeric intensive ideas, so I need to import/require an external numerics library (I'm guessing numlua, https://github.com/carvalho/numlua) in the sandboxed user scripts. I don't mind modifying the original code of berrybots to make it work, and I already assume there is no way around that in the sandbox (but maybe there is?).

On the C++ end the sandbox is started and the standard libraries loaded with

```
*state = luaL_newstate();
lua_setcwd(*state, stateCwd);
luaL_openlibs(*state)
```

I want to load the numlua library as well, which I can normally just import in any lua script with

```
require "numlua"
```

but obviously not in the sandbox.

I know that `luaL_register` is used to register C functions, but I couldn't make it work and I think there should be an easier way to import numlua without going back to the C API of numlua.

I don't care if the solution poses a security risk, since I'm only planning on using it myself. For completeness sake it would be nice though to have a (reasonably) secure solution.

I'm new to lua (mostly familiar with Python/Cython/C), so forgive me if I'm overlooking some obvious stuff.

Comment: The docs says: `only load Lua source files from BerryBots data directories`.  This means you're not allowed to load a library written in C.  But you can modify and rebuild the BerryBots executable ;-)

Comment: Yes that's what I'm writing. Actually I already found that FFI of the luajit is still enabled in the original berrybots, so I'm working on a solution with that.